# Configure Transport Level Security over tcp in a cross domain environment

Tags: tcp, x509certificate, wcf-security, transport-security

I'm trying to implement transport level security for WCF services.
My application architecture is as follows:
WCF service is hosted as windows service in domainA.
Client is a WinForms application in DomainB.
Since it's a cross domain scenario, I have to use certificates for authenticating client and service so they can establish a secure connection.
My understanding is I need 3 certificates to achieve this:

1. Service certificate - authenticates the service to the client.
   Should be installed in Local Machine --> Trusted Root Certificates store on a service machine.
2. Certificate authority - a certificate that can be used to issue user specific certificates. Where should this one be installed? Service or client machine?
3. User certificate.
   Should be installed in Current User --> Trusted Root Certificate on a client machine.

I couldn't find any examples on the web that use certifcate authentication over tcp protocol.
I could only find https examples with services hosted in IIS.
Any reference to a tcp scenario is greatly appreciated.
Are my assumptions correct?
Where should I install the Certificate Authority certificate (item 2)?
Are there other, easier approaches besides using certificates to accomplish transport level security over tcp in a cross domain environments?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Only CA certificate goes to Trusted Root CAs store on both, server and client. End entity certificates are installed in Personal store of corresponding entity (server certificate is installed in Personal store of the Server, client certificate is installed in Personal store of the client).